# Qt ActiveX CoCreateInstance failure (Class not registered) Adobe Reader

Tags: c++, qt, com, activex, acrobat

I have the following code from what I read from on the [qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF):

```
auto pdfObject = new QAxObject("AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF");
qDebug() << pdfObject->dynamicCall("LoadFile(const QString)", "test.pdf");
qDebug() << pdfObject->dynamicCall("Print()");
```

But when I run it I got the message:

```
CoCreateInstance failure (Class not registered)
QAxBase::setControl: requested control AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF could not be instantiated
```

I searched for the dll required `AcroPDF.dll` and found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX` and have Adobe Acrobat Reader DC installed. What can I do make this works?

Comment: Yikes, whomever wrote that wiki entry does not understand beans about the way COM works.  The .NET Regasm.exe utility is a very dangerous gun in the wrong hands.  You can also tell that the safety switch was off when he lists Linux and Mac as possible platforms.  The proper ProgId is "AcroPDF.PDF".  Do avoid taking a dependency on Acrobat, not the kind of program you want to have to support yourself.  Lots and lots of PDF viewers around.

Comment: Possible reason is that ActiveX is 32-bit and your app is 64-bit so it can't find ActiveX

Answer (score 0):

Likely the COM object is not found due to missing registration. Make sure that ActiveX DLL is registered. Use [regsvr32](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx). You might need admin privileges to run it. The command line is:

```
regsvr32 AcroPDF.dll
```